# Backblaze B2 Native URL vs. Friendly URL - transaction caps?

Tags: cloud-storage, backblaze

I'm using B2 as a storage for the images on a website we develop.

Due to the fact, there're millions of images to be served from B2 I'm wondering if there's a difference in using either native URL or friendly URL provided by B2 in terms of transaction caps?

See sample URLs below:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference between those two URLs due to the fact that both are [classed](https://www.backblaze.com/b2/b2-transactions-price.html) as Transaction Class B. This means that their pricing is identical and the free daily limit too.

If you want to reduce your B2 transactions consider using CloudFlare with caching turned on. Another benefit of CloudFlare is that Backblaze won't charge you for bandwidth if you download using CloudFlare.
https://www.cloudflare.com/bandwidth-alliance/backblaze/

Should you need to download from a private bucket via CloudFlare, try using this CloudFlare Worker script I wrote: https://gitlab.com/snippets/1867981

Comment: I'll accept your answer, but there's one important note you're missing so I'll post an edit to the answer 